# Socket program in C cannot compile

Tags: c, sockets

Hi guys I was reading a book about the socket programming and there were two codes client and server.

here is the server code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
void error(char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, newsockfd, portno, clilen;
    char buffer[256];
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    int n;
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no port provided/n");
        exit(1);
    }
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sockfd < 0)
        error("ERROR OPENING SOCKET");
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    portno = atoi(argv[1]);
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) <0)
        error("ERROR on binding");
    listen(sockfd,5);
    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
    newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &client);
    if(newsockfd < 0)
        error("ERROR ON ACCEPT");
    bzero(buffer,256);
    n = read(newsockfd,buffer,255);
    if(n < 0)
        error("ERROR READING FROM SOCKET");
        printf("HERE IS THE MESSAGE: %s\n",buffer);
        n = write(newsockfd,"I GOT YOUR MESSAGE",18);
        if(n < 0)
            error("ERROR WRITING TO SOCKET");
        return 0;
}
```

and here is the client code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>

void error(char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, portno, n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;

    char buffer[256];
    if(argc < 3) {
        fprintf(stderr,"USAGE %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
    }
    portno = atoi(argv[2]);
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sockfd < 0)
        error("ERROR OPENING SOCKET");
    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if(server == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR no such host\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if(connect(sockfd,&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
        error("ERROR CONECTING");
    printf("Please Enter the message: ");
    bzero(buffer,256);
    fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
    n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
    if(n < 0)
    error("ERROR READING THE SOCKET");
    printf("%s\n",buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

But when I compile it with visual studio or turbo c++ or borland c++ they gives me error I have downloaded all the required headers but the problem is still there.

Comment: compile with gcc in Linux, not window sockets

Comment: @nouney The errors are illogical the errors are in headers files the errors are like  `missing ; before identifier`

Comment: Where from did you download the header files?

Comment: Please note, you should not be using the functions named `bzero()`, `bcopy()`, and `atoi()`. The `bzero()` and `bcopy()` functions were deprecated in the previous version of POSIX and are excluded from the current standard. The `atoi()` function is explicitly defined as having no error handling, and is otherwise equivalent to `(int) strtol(str, (char **)NULL, 10)`. [(See also: `strtol()`)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtol.html)

Comment: `bzero()` should be replaced by [`memset()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/memset.html) and `bcopy()` should be replaced by [`memmove()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/memmove.html) (Note: `bcopy(ONE, TWO, THREE)` gets replaced by `memmove(TWO, ONE, THREE)`.)

Comment: @Prof.Falken I downloaded it from http://linux.die.net/include/ just write the name of the header you re looking for like http://linux.die.net/include/stdio.h or http://linux.die.net/include/sys/types.h

Comment: @HaseebAhmadBasil, that explains why you had problems. These are Linux headers and can not be used in Windows. Did you make it work with Cygwin?

Comment: Yes it is working now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are reading examples with the standard "BSD" socket library. Windows uses a slightly different socket library.

For a more general approach, you can port standard BSD sockets programs (what you are reading in your book) to [Winsock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). [Advice here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740096%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Or, if you want a socket compatible system in Windows, you can download Cygwin from http://cygwin.com/ and run your program from there. (Be sure to download the GCC compiler etc in the setup.exe program.)

Comment: can you tell me from where can I download the GCC compiler I have been looking for it but all i found was mirrors but I can't understand what to download

Comment: @HaseebAhmadBasil, for now, it is easiest if you download http://cygwin.com/setup-x86.exe and from within the installer select next, next, until you come to a list of software to select. Expand "devel" and select at least "gcc-g++" and "make".

Answer (score 1):

To build this in Windows, you need to use minGW, or a virtual linux system.