# Cygwin gcc compiling error

Tags: c, sockets, gcc

I was trying to compile a C socket program in CYGWIN gcc but when I compile the client program it gives me the following error

```
client.h: In function ‘error’:
client.h:11:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’ [enabled by default]
     exit(1);
     ^
client.h: In function ‘main’:
client.h:30:9: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’ [enabled by default]
         exit(0);
         ^
client.h:36:5: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘connect’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
     if(connect(sockfd,&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
     ^
In file included from client.h:3:0:
/usr/include/sys/socket.h:28:7: note: expected ‘const struct sockaddr *’ but argument is of type ‘struct sockaddr_in *’
   int connect (int, const struct sockaddr *, socklen_t);
       ^
```

And when I tries to compile the server program it gives me the following error

```
server.h: In function ‘error’:
server.h:8:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’ [enabled by default]
     exit(1);
     ^
server.h: In function ‘main’:
server.h:18:9: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’ [enabled by default]
         exit(1);
         ^
server.h:23:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘bzero’ [enabled by default]
     bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
     ^
server.h:32:64: error: ‘client’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &client);
                                                                ^
server.h:32:64: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

So what is the solution to this

Comment: For starters, don't put code in header files. Just the function declarations.  The .c files is where the actual implementation should be.  That may part of the problem. It sees "exit()" being used in the header file.  Also, show a minimal example (i.e. show us your code) of what is not working.

Comment: you can find my code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17971513/socket-program-in-c-cannot-compile

Comment: Are you including `stdlib.h`? Then you can see that exit is already declared, and you shouldn't declare it again. It is a build in function that should not be redefined.

Comment: I included `stdlib.h` and errors about `exit()` is no longer there but other errors are still there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the issue was that i was trying to compile the linux program in windows.

Answer (score 3):

The error in your client code is because you pass a pointer to a `struct sockaddr_in` to a parameter that expects it to be a pointer to a `struct sockaddr`. The error message basically says it all. The error in your server code is because the variable `client` is not declared anywhere.

The warnings are caused by not including the appropriate include files containing the declarations of `exit` (include `stdlib.h`) and `bzero` (include `strings.h`). You thus get an implicit declaration and since the compiler knows these functions as standardly built-in functions it mentions that in the warning as well.